# Getting separatedBy to work in parboiled2

Tags: scala, parboiled2

This seems pretty simple!

```
class SeparatedParser(val input: ParserInput, val delimiter: String = ",") extends Parser {

  def pipedField = rule { (zeroOrMore(field).separatedBy("|")) }
  def field = rule { capture(zeroOrMore(noneOf(delimiter))) }

  def d = delimiter

  def record = rule {
    field ~ d ~ pipedField ~ d ~ field ~ EOI
  }
}
```

I try:

```
val parser = new SeparatedParser("""49798,piped1|piped2,sklw""")
val parsed = parser.record.run()
parsed match {
  case Success(rel) => println(rel)
  case Failure(pe:ParseError) =>println(parser.formatError(pe)) 
}
```

But I get:

```
49798 :: Vector(piped1|piped2) :: sklw :: HNil
```

I would expect the Vector to have two separate elements: `piped1` and `piped2`.

What dumbass mistake am I making?

Comment: `field` consumes everything until `delimiter` is found. Therefore, if you only look at `piped1|piped2,` it obviously eats everything up to the comma, even the `|`.

Comment: Yep, a dumbass mistake! That works, care to turn that into an answer so I can accept?